# Input 2D char array

Tags: c++

In the following code I am not getting anything as output if I output `a[0]`. Probably it is `a[0]="\n"` but I am unable to understand why?

```
int main() {

    char a[50][80];
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
      {
          cin.getline(a[i],50);
      }
    sort(a,n);

    cout<<a[0];  // New line printed
    cout<<a[1];  // Stores first string

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sort(a,n);
```

is not right.

1. You have to pass `a+n` as the second argument.
2. You have to pass a compare function to compare null terminated C strings.

---

```
sort(a, a+n, [](char* s1, char* s2) { return std::strcmp(s1, s2) < 0; });
```

It will be easier to use `std::vector<std::string>`. Then you can use

```
std::vector<std::string> a;

...


sort(a.begin(), a.end());
```